# Some WPF binding questions

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

In my current project I have a need to display log output into a separate window but for whatever reason I'm not getting it to work. As I'm pretty new to WPF data binding I suspect the problem is me ;O).

Here's how it's supposed to work:

There's three view model classes, each representing a an aggregate for another (digested for clarity)

```
// The VM starting point, using a Singleton instance
// It holds a collection of log "sources", each representing a separate class' logging
internal sealed class ClassLogVM : DependencyObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<object, ClassLogSourceVM> _sourceIndex;
    private readonly object _syncRoot;

    /* dependency property initialization omitted */

    private static ClassLogVM _s_singleton;
    public static ClassLogVM Singleton
    {
        get { return _s_singleton ?? (_s_singleton = new ClassLogVM()); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ClassLogSourceVM> Items
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<ClassLogSourceVM>) GetValue(_s_itemsProp); }
        set { SetValue(_s_itemsProp, value); }
    }

    private void classLogLogged(object sender, ClassLogEventArgs args)
    {
        VM.InvokeInUiThread(() =>
        {
            ClassLogSourceVM source;
            var caller = args.Caller == null ? "(unknown)" : args.Caller.ToString();
            lock (_syncRoot)
                if (!_sourceIndex.ContainsKey(caller))
                {
                    source = new ClassLogSourceVM(caller);
                    ((List<ClassLogSourceVM>) Items).Add(source);
                    _sourceIndex.Add(caller, source);
                }
                else
                    source = _sourceIndex[caller];
            source.Add(new ClassLogItemVM(args.Timestamp, args.Message));
        });
    }

    private ClassLogVM()
    {
        _syncRoot = new object();
        _sourceIndex = new Dictionary<object, ClassLogSourceVM>();
        Items = new List<ClassLogSourceVM>();
        ClassLog.Logged += classLogLogged;
    }
}

// represents a collection of log entries (see: Items property)
public class ClassLogSourceVM : DependencyObject
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(_s_nameProp); }
        set { SetValue(_s_nameProp, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ClassLogItemVM> Items
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<ClassLogItemVM>)GetValue(_s_itemsProp); }
        private set { SetValue(_s_itemsProp, value); }
    }

    public void Add(ClassLogItemVM item)
    {
        ((List<ClassLogItemVM>)Items).Add(item);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetValue(_s_nameProp) + " (Count: " + Items.Count() + ")";
    }

    public ClassLogSourceVM(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        SetValue(_s_nameProp, name);
        Items = new List<ClassLogItemVM>();
    }
}

// represents an individual log entry
public sealed class ClassLogItemVM : DependencyObject
{
    public DateTime Timestamp
    {
        get { return (DateTime) GetValue(_s_timestampProp); }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(_s_messageProp); }
        set { SetValue(_s_messageProp, value); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Timestamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + ": " + Message;
    }

    public ClassLogItemVM(DateTime timestamp, string message)
    {
        SetValue(_s_timestampProp, timestamp);
        SetValue(_s_messageProp, message);
    }
}
```

This is how I set up the XAML (user control called "ClassLogView") ...

```
<UserControl x:Class="GeDevelop.GVSViewer.Views.Debug.ClassLogView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:Debug="clr-namespace:GeDevelop.GVSViewer.ViewModel.Debug" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
         DataContext="{Binding Debug:ClassLogVM.Singleton.Items}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="sources" Source="{Binding}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Source" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Debug:ClassLogSourceVM}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid d:DataContext="{Binding Debug:ClassLogVM.Singleton}">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sources}}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Debug:ClassLogSourceVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

The result is the Treeview is empty.

Now, my questions are:
1. What have I missed, causing the TreeView to display nothing?
2. I need to programmatically assign the DataContext to the user control despite the fact I have stated it in the  tag. Why?

Would appreciate an explanation. WPF sure isn't for the faint hearted... ;O)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know that's not how you create DependencyProperties. DependencyObject is the core/base class of most of the UIElements, i would be very cautious to base my class on it.

Google or search in StackOverflow for DependencyProperty if you really want to use it.

In most cases, wrapping your DomainModel/BusinessObject with INotifyPropertyChanged is more than enough to get WPF binding pick it up

Comment: Why do you say that's not how you create DependencyProperties? OP left out the actual DependencyProperty.Register calls, but otherwise it looks legit. Admittedly it's a bit unusual to descend ViewModel objects from DependencyObject since it's a hard dependency on an assembly that many consider to belong to the UI layer, but that's somewhat subjective -- if you've got something to gain from using DependencyObjects, it might be worth it.

Comment: I have built other VM-classes based on `DependencyObject` with success. Although, I have seen other developers warn against doing this and recommend the use of `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead. I tried this but bindings that worked with the DO approach doesn't seem to work with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I have no idea why.

Comment: main point if you ViewModel should not have any dependency on UI, that means you want to use your ViewModel with other Views, you wil lhave to ship WPF assemblies with it

Comment: I claim the VM in this case is not dependent on the UI. Any suggestions as to why the binding fails to produce and visible results?